# Is onafterpaste valid in <h:inputText?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I need to validate some code in a project. One part of the project is using js/richface 4.2

Using Netbean as the development tool, it complains the attribute onafterpaste is not defined in the component inputText in a portion of code shown below.

Is onafterpaste valid inside inputText in the portion of code below?

```
<h:inputText id="displayRowsFup" style="width: 100px;margin-right:10px;text-align:left;" value="${dashboard.paginationVw.pageSize}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');" onafterpaste="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"/>
```

Comment: Of course not. But now I'm curious too - who and why did someone put that? What does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a valid attribute, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html).

BTW, first time I am hearing about this event, where did this come from?

Comment: I did a search on web and it seems to be html event, http://www.webdbtips.com/122487/ The code is from vendor and I guess its copy paste work and intend to allow only numeric when onkeyup event, or when pasting into the text etc. Guess may need to substitute the onafterpaste with onchange. I wasn't sure if it was valid because I'm skeptical to netbean warning/error and that nothing found with the netbean warning the attribute onafterpaste is not defined in the component.